# Use blazor with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I would like to create a blazor app or page. I would like to deploy this to Sharepoint library and from there I could call the code. Is there a way to host blazor dlls in SharePoint as they get blocked by sharepoint? Or is there another possibility?

SharePoint 2013 and Sharepoint 2016.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or specific version of SharePoint server on-premises?  Are you using modern sites or classic sites?

Comment: it is SharePoint on prems.

Comment: Which **Version**?

Comment: SP 2013 and SP2016

Answer (score 2):

Look into provider hosted apps. A provider hosted app is a an app running somewhere else, that can be surfaced inside of SharePoint. Also, the app is provided context info, so it knows which site, user, etc., the app is being called from. One possible experience for the end user: the navigate to a sharepoint site, and on the page are three web parts. One web part is actually an iframe that is showing content from an asp.net blazor app running on a different server.

edit: alternatively, the blazor app could be installed on a separate IIS site on the same server as SharePoint. I don't think this is a great idea, but it would work.